# Computing a discounted sum within if-statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, sum

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate the following discounted sum for different lengths in an `if`-statement.

Basically, I want to do the following calculation in an `if` statement:

```
if value[0] - mean > delta ** 1 * value[1] + delta ** 2 * value[2] + delta ** 3 * value[3]:
   continue
```

where `delta = 0.9` for example and the `value` belongs to a list of numbers.

I tried the following, but it does not really seem to work until now:

```
if value[0] - mean > np.sum([delta ** i * value[i] for i in range(1,k)]):
   continue
```

where `k = 3` in this example but should be variable to different lengths.

How could I efficiently achieve this?

Many thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the below values

```
lst_value = [10,11,12]
k = 3
delta = 0.9

if lst_value[0] - mean > sum([delta ** index * lst_value[val] for index,val in enumerate(range(k))]):
      continue
```